# Did Aegon have an army?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

When Aegon the conqueror crossed the narrow seas in *Game of Thrones* did he come with any sort of army or was it just his family and his dragons?

Comment: I don't think there was any information provided about that in the *tv series.*

Comment: I don't think the details have been mention yet in the TV show - but the wiki page mentions a small army http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_of_Conquest

Comment: As @JudgeDredd mentioned, there is not much information about this in the TV shows, but you're welcome to leave this question here or migrate it to [scifi.stackexchange.com](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/) for further insights!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the books as a reference, Aegon Targaryen landed with a small small army composed of the Targaryen levies and those of their few vassals (chief among them the Baratheons and the Velaryons). But more importantly he had the three dragons Balerion, Vhaegar and Meraxes ridden by him and his two sisters/wives